# Serializing an object to file creates blank object in file

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

I am trying to create an object that is then serialized and written to file but regardless of what I try, a blank object is always written to file instead.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class FileIO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private VIAModel viaModel1;
    private VIAView viaView1 = new VIAView();
    private VIAController viaContr = new VIAController();

    public void setVIAModelFromFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, EOFException {
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("viaModel.ser");
        ObjectInputStream inputFile = new ObjectInputStream(fstream);

        while (!endOfFile) {
            try {
                viaModel1 = (VIAModel) inputFile.readObject();
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                endOfFile = true;
            }
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }

    public void setToFile() throws IOException {
        viaContr = viaView1.getController();
        viaModel1.setEventList(viaContr.getVIAMod().getEventList());
        System.out.println(viaModel1.getEventList().getListOfEvents());
        FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("viaModel.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream outputFile = new ObjectOutputStream(fstream);

        try {
            outputFile.writeObject(viaModel1);
            outputFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public VIAModel getVIAModel() {
        return viaModel1;
    }

    public void setVIAModel(VIAModel viamod) {
        this.viaModel1 = viamod;
    }

}
```

The object being written has serializable on all objects inside and objects unable to be serialized have been manually serialized. The system.out.print shows the object with the information entered in the program, but this information doesn't appear in the .ser file at all and so only a blank object is read later.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Events implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5596571541918537611L;
private transient SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty date = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty duration = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty type = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty location = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty category = new SimpleStringProperty("");
// private Lecturer conductor;
private transient SimpleStringProperty price = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty minPartic = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private transient SimpleStringProperty maxPartic = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private boolean isFinalized = false;
// ArrayList<Members> eventMembList = new ArrayList<>();

public Events(String name, String date, String duration, String type, String location, String category,
        /* Lecturer conductor, */ String price, String minPartic, String maxPartic, boolean isFinalized) {
    setName(name);
    setDate(date);
    setDuration(duration);
    setType(type);
    setLocation(location);
    setCategory(category);
    setPrice(price);
    setMinPartic(minPartic);
    setMaxPartic(maxPartic);
    this.isFinalized = isFinalized;
}

public Events() {
    this("","","","","","","","","",false);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getDate() {
    return date.get();
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date.set(date);
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration.get();
}

public void setDuration(String duration) {
    this.duration.set(duration);
}

public String getType() {
    return type.get();
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type.set(type);
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location.get();
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location.set(location);
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category.get();
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category.set(category);
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price.get();
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price.set(price);
}

public String getMinPartic() {
    return minPartic.get();
}

public void setMinPartic(String minPartic) {
    this.minPartic.set(minPartic);
}

public String getMaxPartic() {
    return maxPartic.get();
}

public void setMaxPartic(String maxPartic) {
    this.maxPartic.set(maxPartic);
}

public boolean isFinalized() {
    return isFinalized;
}

public void setFinalized(boolean isFinalized) {
    this.isFinalized = isFinalized;
}

public void finalizeEvent() {
    this.isFinalized = true;
}
// public void addMemToEvent(Members member) {
// eventMembList.add(member);
// }
public String toString() {
    return this.name + "\n" +   this.date+ "\n" + this.duration+ "\n" + this.type+ "\n" +   this.location+ "\n" +   this.category+ "\n" + this.price+ "\n" + this.minPartic+ "\n" + this.maxPartic+ "\n" + this.isFinalized;
}

public void readExternal(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    name = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    date = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    duration = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    type = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    location = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    category = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    price = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    minPartic = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
    maxPartic = new SimpleStringProperty((String) in.readObject());
}

public void writeExternal(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    out.writeObject(name.get());
    out.writeObject(date.get());
    out.writeObject(duration.get());
    out.writeObject(type.get());
    out.writeObject(location.get());
    out.writeObject(category.get());
    out.writeObject(price.get());
    out.writeObject(minPartic.get());
    out.writeObject(maxPartic.get());

}
```

}

Comment: Define ' information doesn't appear in the .ser file at all'.

Comment: My apologies. The .ser file shows a blank object without the content that was in the viaModel1 object that was written to it.

Comment: Shows it how? And where are the definitions of `ViaModel`, `ViaView`, and `VIAController`?

Comment: It's very difficult to explain without posting the entire project, which I hear is frowned upon. Essentially, viaModel is made up of an eventsList object, a memberList object and a lecturerList object. Each of those stores a number of event, member and lecturer objects. In my controller, these are created by a button click and strings added to the object as it's attributes(hopefully that makes sense). viaModel here contains each of these objects but when I read the viaModel back from file it lists an empty viaModel.

Comment: It is not acceptable to post partial questions here, or what you *think* the code does. For example, it is entirely possible that none of the classes I mentioned have non-transient non-static fields, in which case your expectations are Olympian.

Comment: I have added an example of one Object in the edit to the above code if this helps. Is further information required to clarify?

Comment: Also, just to clarify a little further. It seems that what is being output to the .ser file is null values for all of the attributes of the object, not simply an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Changing SimpleStringProperty to String seems to work perfectly and eliminates all of the issues involved with serializing, which is something that I don't have the knowledge to correct.

Answer (score 0):

in your below code you will end up reading only the last object make sure you are reading correct contents from input file. Did you tried populating a new `VIAModel` object and then writing it to the file

```
 while (!endOfFile) {
        try {
            viaModel1 = (VIAModel) inputFile.readObject();
        } catch (EOFException eof) {
            endOfFile = true;
    }
```

Comment: It has been intentionally set up that only 1 object is being written to file and 1 object read from file. All other objects are contained within this object. The first thing I did was create a blank object in the file, which is read at start. The object can be edited and then it is saved to file just prior to the closing of the program. The system.out.print of viaModel1 in the code above shows any added objects but for some reason these are not output to the file.

Comment: No real reason I guess. I'll remove the loop now.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as I said. You have

```
public class Events implements Serializable
```

and a whole series of `transient` fields, and also

```
public void readExternal(ObjectInputStream in)
```

and

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutputStream out)
```

*These methods are never called.* There is nothing in the Object Serialization Specification about either of these method signatures.

If you want this class to be serialized, you need to either remove `transient` throughout, if `SimpleStringProperty` is `Serializable`, and remove these methods, or make it `extends Externalizable`, and fix the resulting compilation errors.

What you *can't* do is just make up your own semantics and signatures and then wonder why Java doesn't implement them.

Comment: My apolagies if any of this seems ignorant. I am currently studying and am very much out of my depth with this if I am to be honest. I implemented the changes as you said and get an error.
    guiView.VIAModel; Serializable incompatible with Externalizable

Comment: You implemented which changes? I gave you alternatives.

Comment: Sorry. Only one of the methods was possible. SimpleStringProperty is not serializable so removing transient won't work. I tried the second method and got that error. I then realised that I could instead use readObject and writeObject from Serializable without having to use Externalizable.